# Is it ok to create thread in thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

So i have 4 objects. Each one of them must execute up to 5 operations simultaneously and also all 4 object must be operated simultaneously. I created one thread for each object and inside 5 new threads ? I saw that after a period the threads are not executed anymore.
The question is : Is it ok to have thread in thread? or it's better to create a thread pool and run them in concurrency?

Comment: It is "OK", as in sure, you can do it. The question is more about - did you manage your threads and shared data correctly?

Comment: Also - depending on what you actually need to do - creating threads may not be the best way to go. You can look at `Task Parallel Library` - this may be useful.

Comment: Regarding shared data is ok regarding threads management im not that sure since threads are not executed after a while

Comment: Apart from that, threads are not "inside each other", you create a new thread in the process, so they are on the same level.

Comment: You should post your code here. Chances are you've did something _else_ wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "thread in a thread". Thread is entity that is global in whole process. It doesn't matter if it is created in one of other thread. The moment it is created, it becomes global and unrelated to thread it created it.

More about creating threads, you should be worried about access to shared resources and possible race conditions which might be much harder to track when threads are created in different places.

And from you description, I would recommend you to look at Task Parallel Library, which makes problems like this breeze.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok. You actually need to do that sometimes, like when you're working with servers, you can create thread for each connected client from thread where you are listening for clients.